# Android_Core MasterChooser Java Invalid Syntax Error

Tags: ros-jade, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the basic masterchooser built into the android rosjava_core and I am struggling to connect the robot to my phone. I receive this error:

Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://192.168.137.118 :51762/

I have set the ip in the master chooser as http://192.168.137.118:11311 and additionally have set the
ip in the android hosts file but it still does not work.  I am using the code from an open github repo that uses the base code https://github.com/ollide/rosjava_android_template

Any help is appreciated, thank you. The robot is using ROS jade.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/315264/android_core-masterchooser-java-invalid-syntax-error/) by [iShauny](https://answers.ros.org/users/39960/ishauny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iShauny](https://answers.ros.org/users/39960/ishauny/) on 2019-02-11**:
I am unsure why this port is showing up if I am honest, I am not sure what part of the source code for the master chooser is adding that port into the url.

**Comment by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) on 2019-02-12**:
Hmm the URI contains both the protocol (http), the IP address or host, and the port; all of that is entered by the user manually in the master chooser.
Try using [pubsub](https://github.com/rosjava/android_core/tree/kinetic/android_tutorial_pubsub) tutorial as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://192.168.137.118 :51762/` --> there's a space between the address and the port; what about that?

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2019-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0